# PDO ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = false, SHOW TABLES LIKE и синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: mysql, pdo

Вот такая ошибка

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

возникает при попытке подготовить запрос вида

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE :1
```

при отключении эмуляции подготавливаемых запросов в коде

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root', [
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    ]);
$sth = $conn->prepare('SHOW TABLES LIKE :1'); <-- тут ошибка
$sth->execute([':1' => 'test']);
var_dump($sth->fetchAll());
```

PHP 7.0.4 и 5.6.13
MySQL 5.6.20
Windows 7 :)

**Вопрос:** Что делать? Это мой локальный глюк или PDO глобально кривой?

**UPD**
С запросом вида

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `test` LIKE ?
```

аналогичная ситуация.

Comment: Попробуйте с позиционным параметром ?, а не именованным. Вообще странная мысль в качестве именованного параметра использовать число.

Comment: @Мелкий, пробовал и `?`, и ':table', ошибка не пропадает пока не удаляю `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,`. В запросах с `SELECT` и `LIKE` ошибок нет.

Comment: Ну почему сразу "PDO глобально кривой"? ПДО дает тебе принципиальную возможность исполнить запрос, в котором пв не поддерживаются, а ты его за это и хаешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysql> prepare stmt1 from 'show tables like ?';
>   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Сдаётся мне, что prepared statements в mysql в принципе не могут обрабатывать запросы show tables.

[Точно](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), об этом упомянуто в мануале. В mysql разрешено подготавливать только определённый список выражений, `SHOW TABLES` и `SHOW COLUMNS` в список поддерживаемых выражений не входят. А эмуляция подготовленных выражений, соответственно, успешно это ограничение скрывает.

Используйте запросы к псевдотаблицам служебной базы `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME
FROM    
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES    
WHERE    
  table_schema = DATABASE() AND    
  table_name LIKE ?;
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: _Сдаётся мне, что prepared statements в mysql в принципе не могут обрабатывать запросы show tables._ Всё проще. SHOW - это вообще не запросы, а процедуры.