# Проверка наличия таблицы в БД

Tags: php, mysqli

Итак, я от пользователя получаю название таблицы, из которой он хочет получить данные, и я должен проверить наличие этой таблицы. Как я понял, надо использовать `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table_name'`, но какой его синтаксис в `php`?

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', '', 'root');
$mysqli->query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
$tables = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE `pages`');
$mysqli->close();
echo $tables;
require_once 'header.php';
require_once 'body.php';
?>
```

Создал такую страничку для теста этой функции, но ничего не выводится, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, если не поможет - попробую копнуть глубже

Comment: а что вы ожидаете увидеть в echo ? $mysqli->query возвращает объект. А что там дальше посмотрите в phpmyadmin, например, сначала

Comment: я уже боюсь несколько за логику и безопасность вашего приложения, если пользователь  может  указывать любые таблицы.

Comment: @splash58 я попробовал обычный fetch_row и оно выдало ошибку: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on boolean in /storage/ssd5/594/1467594/public_html/index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/594/1467594/public_html/index.php on line 7

Comment: значит, query вернуло false. Надо смотреть ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Был [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635700/pdo-attr-emulate-prepares-false-show-tables-like-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0) в PDO и там пришли к выводу, что:

> prepared statements в mysql в принципе не могут обрабатывать запросы show tables.

1. Не нужно напрямую вставлять в запрос... ничего, вообще ничего, для этого есть подготовленные выражения. Ну и плюс из ответа по ссылке грустно меняем короткий `SHOW TABLES` на запрос к `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

   ```
   $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', '', 'root');
   $mysqli->query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
   $sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
       WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND table_name LIKE ?;";
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $table_name);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($tables);
   $stmt->fetch();
   $stmt->close();
   if (!empty($tables)) {
       // таблица есть
   } else {
       // таблицы нет
   }
   ```
2. Ну и, наконец, как правильно сказали в комментариях - в принципе нехорошо, когда пользователь может получить данные из какой хочет таблицы просто по названию. Заведите массив, например, в котором будут перечислены названия таблиц, которые можно запрашивать - и сверяйте с ним. Можете сделать функцию для этого, завести класс - как угодно. Хоть в базе хранить (да, вот так вот, в *базе* хранить названия таблиц *базы*, которые пользователь может запрашивать).

Comment: мне вот кажется, что если есть массив с названиями таблиц,  то и сами таблицы там перечисленные должны существовать. Так что вообще не ясно, зачем вся эта канитель.

Comment: @teran, и правда, не подумал что-то. Ну как бы, если ему очень нужно именно таким образом - то пункты 1 и 2 отвечают на его вопрос. А третий пункт - это пожелание просто.